# Multiple modal code not showing any modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have been stuck on this question for a while now as I do not know much on using script in html. I'm trying to get 4 images to show their image bigger on a modal when they are clicked, however it does not seem to be working? The w3-hover-opacity does also not seem to be working which I'm not sure if it has something to do with this problem?

I am using this as a reference: 
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp

Thanks

```
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h2> 3D Models and Animation</h2>
    <p1>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
 from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
 professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the
 more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and
 going through the cites of the word in classical literature,
 discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections
 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise
 on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The
 first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
 a line in section 1.10.32</p1>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-3 modelimages">
            <img  src="3D/deformation.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" alt="deformation animation" class="img-responsive center-block
 w3-hover-opacity">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 modelimages"> 
            <img src="3D/car.jpg" alt="car"  class="img-responsive center-block" onclick="onClick(this)">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 modelimages">
            <img src="3D/deformation.jpg" alt="deformation animation"  class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 modelimages">
            <img src="3D/deformation.jpg" alt="deformation animation"  class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>

        <div id="modal01" class="w3-modal" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
             <span class="w3-button
 w3-hover-red w3-xlarge w3-display-topright">&times;</span>   
             <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
                <img id="img01" style="width:100%">   
             </div> 
         </div>

<script> 
    function onClick(element) {               
        document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;  
      document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block"; 
    }
</script>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you import w3.css?

Comment: Adding this to your head tag fixes the issue as @StrangerintheQ highlighted.  
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`

Comment: Hello, thanks I added this to the the top which fixed the hover animation but there is still no modal? Do you have any other ideas?